# Outlook - create template for making event in specific calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, templates

is possible to create template which create a new event in specific calendar?

Use case:
I have "My calendar" and "Shared calendar" (My calendar is default calendar). I have template for Shared calendar (Availibity, notification, Subject prefix are set there). Shortcut for this template is pinned to Outlook taskbar icon - a new event from template can be made for two clicks.

But everytime, My calendar is set as folder for a new event created from template. When I want to change it I must click File, Change folder, select folder, go back and then save event.

How to avoid it?

I wanted to use "published forms" for it, but in forms I cannot set availibility and notifications. Also I want to modify this template and distribute it to my BFU coleagues (I cannot imagine how to distribute form to them).

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use a template outside Outlook to create a meeting to a specific calendar. When you open a template or other outlook item from outside outlook, it always uses the default folders.

Try using "published forms". Then publish the form to a organizational forms library so than all users who have access to the library could use that form. See: [How to create & publish Organizational Forms in Exchange 2013/Office 365.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exota/2015/08/16/how-to-create-publish-organizational-forms-in-exchange-2013office-365/)